# Find $\sup$ and $\inf$ of $A$ and justify

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

$$A=\left \{x\in \Bbb R :x<\dfrac{2}{x} \right \}.$$

a) $\sup A = -1$ since $\max A=-1;$

b) $\inf A$ does not exist since $A$ is not bounded below.

Is this the only justifications? Can anyone check if this is correct?

Comment: The set A is not clear, did you mean $A=\{x\in R:x<\frac{2}{x}\}$?

Comment: @JrAntalan yes I mean this.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $A:=\{x\in\mathbb R\mid x<\frac2{x}\}$ then $$A=(-\infty,-\sqrt2)\cup(0,\sqrt2)$$

Comment: then Sup A = sqrt2 and inf A does not exist since A is not bounded below.

Comment: That is good thinking!

Comment: is this the only justification?or there are some that I missed?

Comment: Well, $\sqrt2$ is clearly an upper bound of $A$ and there are no smaller upperbounds. Secondly $A$ has no lower bounds. This justifies the conclusions mentioned in your comment. That's really enough.